# Laravel - Update models relations to another model

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent-relationship

I have a many-to-many relationship between an incident model and a Patient model. An incident can have many patients and a patient can be involved in many incidents.

Should it occur that a user creates duplicates of a patient model we want to be able to merge those two patient models into one. This means that I want to move the incidents that patient 1 is involved in to patient 2 including additional attributes that are sitting on the pivot table.

I've tried something as simple as

```
Casualty::where('patient_id', $patientOne->getKey())->update(['patient_id' => $patientTwo->getKey()]);
```

But this doesn't work. Using the `updateOnExistingPivot()` method would mean I need to iterate over every incident for patient 1 and run a separate DB query to update the patient to patient 2.

I've also tried updating the record like this

```
$patientOne->incidents()->update(['patient_id' => $patientTwo->getKey()]);
```

This also doesn't work because there is no **patient_id** column on the incidents table.

How can I achieve this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know if I am understanding this issue correctly, but it seems like you are combining two things in the same query. I would keep it separate the creation of the incidents / patients and the pivot insertion. If you have set up your relationships correctly, you should be able to use the sync method or attach method - see https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations and https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you, you want to group more patients into the same accident? You could go with the `belongsToMany` relation and make one pivot table. Then, when you want to update the data simply use the `sync` method.

You can also try storing them with `json_encode()` in one column which will hold only users ID's and later on retrieve them.

Sorry, can't give more info since the question is not described that well.